# How to gather multiple int properties from a list of objects in a list of integers using lambda or linq?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have tried this C# code:

```
//items is the list of objects that contain the property a (int) and b(int)
var listOfInts= items.Select(p => new {p.a, p.b}).Distinct().
                            OrderByDescending(p => p.a).ToList();               

//the result is a list of a' wew {p.a, p.b} AND not a list of integers.
```

I just want these two properties for all objects to be added to a simple list of integers, either linq or lambda expressions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Select(p => p.a)` maybe?

Comment: `(p => new[] ` notice how to declare new array[] you're missing `new []`

Comment: p => new {p.a, p.b} this is working fine.Give it a shot. The problem is that for every object I want these two properties every time to be added to the range of a list of integers.So, Select(p => p.a) will get only one of these two values.

Comment: Yes the answer is SelectMany... I have never used this one before as a newbie to C#. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`:

```
var listOfInts = items.SelectMany(p => new[] { p.a, p.b })
                      .Distinct()
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                      .ToList();
```

Comment: Ohh my friend thanks a lot. It works fine! thank you.